# Flex 4 headerWordWrap in AdvancedDataGridColumn does not work

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, advanceddatagrid

I have tried various options to get headerWordWrap to work with an AdvancedDataGridColumn.  I've even tried using headerWordWrap as a property in the AdvancedDataGrid.  Nothing works. Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Any help would be very much appreciated:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid
    id="gridAvailableQuals"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    dataProvider="{this.handler.qualCodes}"
    doubleClickEnabled="true"
    dragEnabled="true"
    dropEnabled="true"
    dragMoveEnabled="true"
    allowMultipleSelection="true"
    variableRowHeight="true"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="auto"
    headerWordWrap="true"
    itemDoubleClick="this.shtlQuals.addOneItem()">

<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn
    headerText="Item Code"
    dataField="code"
    width="50"
    headerWordWrap="true">
```

Comment: I don't know from the top of my head, but if anything, you can always create an item renderer for the header and have it multiline from there.

Comment: I've never been able to get `headerWordWrap` to work correctly either. As a side note, you can use `&#13;` to start a new line manually in your headers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of headerWordWrap="true", try giving wordWrap="true" for each column like:

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn
headerText="Item Code"
dataField="code"
width="50"
wordWrap="true">
```

And set width property for all the columns...Otherwise width will be taken randomly and header look clumsy... :)

Answer (score 1):

The **headerWordWrap** works but it doesn't accommodate according to header row height, so on UI it appears as not working.

Set the **headerHeight** property of datagrid as needed for static headers, for dynamic headers keep calculating height. It will accommodate the Header text with word wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Setting headerWordWrap property to true allows multi-line headers. You will also need to set the Column width to force the text to wrap, and you'll probably need to set the header height since the default isn't tall enough to fit two lines of text.

Answer (score 0):

headerWordWrap="true"

Set this property in **AdvancedDataGridColumn**

`<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn 
          dataField="data1" 
          headerText="Data 1"
          headerWordWrap="true" 
          wordWrap="true" >
 </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>`

This worked well for me.